# Firebase auth crashes app with an error message: Task is not yet complete

Tags: android, firebase, android-layout, firebase-authentication

Following is my code to check if user is already signed in or not.

```
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
currentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
```

If current user has some data, i get `Token`

```
 if(currentUser != null){
   String token = currentUser.getIdToken(false).getResult().getToken();
}
```

and here it crashes, not always, most of the times with following error message.

```
Method threw 'java.lang.IllegalStateException' exception.
Task is not yet complete
```

I am using the exact code what firebase is using in their documentation.

sometimes it also gets crashes with the same error message i shared above, when i try to sign in.

```
   firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously()
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

                        if(user != null){

                            String userId = user.getUid();
                            String token = user.getIdToken(false).getResult().getToken();

                        }

                    } else {
                        Log.w("", "signInAnonymously:failure", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to access the result directly .  I have faced this issue in past and I was making the same mistake .  **String token = currentUser.getIdToken(false).getResult().getToken();**

Instead you can try using the below code . Hope this might help

```
user.getIdToken(true).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<GetTokenResult>() {
  @Override
   public void onSuccess(GetTokenResult result) {
     String idToken = result.getToken();
     //Do whatever
     Log.d(TAG, "GetTokenResult result = " + idToken);
  }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks @Mini Chip, this worked :) 
Can you please tell me the difference between `user.getIdToken(true)` && `(false)`